# Formal and informal words for sexual body parts

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice, word-usage

**Which are the formal and the informal words for these parts?**
(My dictionary gives me lots of words but I don't know which are the most frequently used ones and if they are polite or not)

Penis = 페니스 / 음경 / 남근 / 고추

Testicles = 고환 / 정소 / 불알

Vulva = 외음부 / 음문 / 보지

Butt = 엉덩이 / 궁댕이 / 궁둥이 / 궁디

Anus = 항문 / 똥꼬 / 똥구멍

I would thank if you could tell me which one is used most in formal speaking and in informal (vulgar) speaking.

Comment: What dictionary did you consult? Some of them are dialect or non-standard words. Medical terms (usually made up of Chinese characters) are considered formal.

Answer (score 3):

Penis = (Formal) 음경 / 남근 / 
        (Informal) 고추
        (Slang) 좆 / 자지

Testicles = (Formal) 고환 / 정소 
            (Informal) 불알

Vulva = (Formal) 외음부 / 음문 
        (Informal/Slang) 보지

Butt = (Formal) 둔부, 볼기, 엉덩이, 궁둥이
       (Informal) 궁댕이/ 궁디

Anus = (Formal) 항문 
       (Informal) 똥꼬 / 똥구멍

With close friends, it's possible to use informal words.
Otherwise, I would recommend formal ones and not to use slang ones.

Comment: I'd say "엉덩이" and "궁둥이" are not that informal. There is also "볼기".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I need to edit.